# Volley DefaultRetryPolicy when Connectivity is Spotty

Tags: android-networking, android-volley

I am using Android's Volley to retrieve JSON files and images.  Overall the performance is fantastic.  I set a progress indicator before starting the request using

```
 getSherlockActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

and turn it off when the request is complete (in onResponse() or onErrorResponse().

My problem is on the train, especially in a tunnel, where connectivity is spotty.  Frequently, the progressbar will persist for what seems like 8 or 10 seconds.  When using volley, I am setting the DefaultRetryPolicy as follows:

```
 jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(2500, 2, 1.0f));

 requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

Are there any suggestions to exit quicker when connectivity is poor?